Hide legend values for one layer when two layers are mapped to the same aesthetic
I'd like to create a Cleveland dot plot where the segment is colored according to the identity of the larger value. The code below is based on the code here
I'm almost there, but the issue is the that I don't want "yes" and "no" to show up in the  legend. Since both dot and segment layers are mapped to color, I don't know how to turn off the legend for one layer but not the other. show.legend does not seem to have any effect in this case.
value1 <- abs(rnorm(26))*2

data <- data.frame(
  x=LETTERS[1:26], 
  value1=value1, 
  value2=value1+1+rnorm(26, sd=1) 
) %>%
  mutate(gt=ifelse(value1>value2,'yes','no'))

dataLong <- data %>% select(-gt) %>% pivot_longer(cols=-x)

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data=data, aes(x=x, xend=x, y=value1, yend=value2,color=gt),show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data=dataLong, aes(x=x,y=value,color=name),size=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(yes='red',no='blue',value1='red',value2='blue'))



show.legend=FALSE is used to prevent the geom from being displayed in the legend key. But you can use the breaks= argument of the scale to specify the categories you want to show in the legend:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    data = data, aes(x = x, xend = x, y = value1, yend = value2, color = gt),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_point(data = dataLong, aes(x = x, y = value, color = name), size = 3) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(yes = "red", no = "blue", value1 = "red", value2 = "blue"),
    breaks = c("value1", "value2")
  )


